# Get base url in css file

Tags: css, base-url

Is there a way to load base url for background-image in css file? for example:

```
background-image: url('{base_url}/myimage.jpg');
background-repeat: repeat;
```

Comment: I don't think you can get base url in CSS. Why you want to keep the image in the root folder?

Comment: @KalyanChakravarthiV for research purpose

Comment: In that case you may need to write your own magento handler if CSS has special syntax for rendering base url. Or else keep that piece of CSS code in phtml file and include it somewhere in the head section. It may solve your problem.

Comment: no such way,use inline in your phtml file

Comment: Just a side note: Having a need of specifying the base url in a CSS file actually tells me that your image is not located at a place where it is supposed to be. Usually you would - as an example - put your CSS file somewhere at `skin/frontend/theme/theme/css/` - and your images than would be in `skin/frontend/theme/theme/images/`. Per that structure you then would specify your background path as `background-image: url('../images/myimage.jpg')`. I mean to say, you're better off checking _why_ you actually have a need for the base url (i.e. why is your image located in the webroot) and fix that.